# Fetching bulk data into resultset

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Is there any performance issue in fetching bulk data into result set in java.

```
rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * from ABC")
```

Table ABC is having bulk amount of data (say 1 million)

What will be the performance improvement while fetching data iteratively as small chunks of 1000 rows at a time and doing operation on it.

Comment: This depends on the database and the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use only selected column with limit of data in mysql like:

```
rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT  columnname1,columnname2,.. from ABC 
                  LIMIT 10000, 30 ")
```

Comment: but this query is db specific . is'nt it?

Comment: yes, because each database have different syntex, it's just a examaple

Answer (score 0):

To a certain extent this depends on the type of database you are connecting to and the driver that you are using. For large datasets you should use:

```
Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY);
st.setFetchSize(<n>);
```

where n is a number of rows to fetch.

This will tell the driver not to pull all the data over in one lump. The fetch size is a hint to tell the driver how much to fetch if it is empty.

In general it is better to let the jdbc driver handle this rather than try and implement it yourself.

This [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) tells about as much as you'd ever want to know about cursors.

Comment: But i cannot use ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY. becoz incase of any error i wanna resume from that previously commited point (for this i am writing previosly committed value into one file) so i'm using following code   
`Statement st = DBConnection.getSrcConn().createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);`